# How do I mark an unit test method as obsolete, or should I keep the method at all?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have some test methods that are no longer needed, could there be any reason to keep those tests and mark them as obsolete (if so, is using 'obsolete' method attribute a proper way to do that)? Or should I just simply remove them?

Comment: Just remove them, they are noise*. Getting them back, should you ever need to, is what Source Control is for. (*Unless they are showing how to use the class in question - in which case they would be better off in a demo program.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are using MsTest you have several options.

1. Add the [Ignore] attribute to the [TestMethod]
2. Remove the [TestMethod] Attribute
3. Remove the code
4. // the code :)

If you're really sure you won't need it anymore, i'd remove it.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you should remove them. They serve no purpose and simply become a maintenance issue, as if you change the code they use you will have to change the tests. They also add to the mental weight of grokking the code base.

As long as your code is in source control the code should be recoverable if you ever need to.

Answer (score 3):

If the test method won't ever be needed, just remove it. Otherwise you'll have to adjust the method to make it compile when you refactor the sut(System Under Test). There is no reason to maintain a method which is never needed.

If you want to prevent running the test method temporarily, depends upon your unittesting framework there will be an option. For example nunit has [IgnoreAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=ignore&r=2.6.3) which can temporarily ignore the test method.